# How to work on multiple windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C# WPF application which does some data processing.. Since the application takes some time to do the processing, sometimes the window freezes. So I am basically trying to find a way so the user doesnt freak out.. I was thinking of producing a second window when the processing is going on with some stats while the main window stays either in background or hidden until the processing is completed whichever works better. Maybe that will prevent things from freezing up or atleast hide it?

At the moment, I tried creating a second window when the processing starts by using the following code... but I am not sure how I would edit the XAML for it. I'm using VS 2013 and only see the XAML for my initial window. Any help will be appreciated!

```
    Window win = new Window();
    win.Show();
    win.Activate();
```

Comment: For simplicity, if your application do nothing, except data processing, you have no reason to use multiple threads. As you has mentioned, you can show some information popup dialog like "Calculation is in progress...", when the calculation is started, and hide window, for example when  OnFinished event has occured.

Comment: In well designed application there sould be only single window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last time I worked in WPF, i don't think it can handle multiple windows very well. Even so, it wouldn't solve your problem. Your problem is that your long running task is running on the same thread as your UI.

The true solution to your problem is Asynchronous coding. For background info, check out the .net TPL, as well as async/await features. These are available in .net 4.0 and 4.5 ,respectively.

Here's an example of how you would use it.

```
private async void BeginProcessingAsync(Data d)
{
    //Show to user that task is running
    this.IsLoading = true; // Show a loading icon or something.

    //Execute the long running task asynchronously
    await Task.Run(() =>  LongRunningMethod(d));

    //Anything after the await line will be executed only after the task is finished.
    this.IsLoading = false;
    DoSomethingWithFinishedData(d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. Also, for anyone using this solution.. if your project targets `.NET 4.0`, use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` instead of `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should run your long-running processing on a different thread or in the background.

One easy way to do this is with a `BackgroundWorker`

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        //put the long running process in here.
    };

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: `bw.DoWork += (s,e) =>`  what does that part mean?

Comment: that is creating an anonymous event handler. `s` is the `sender` of the event, `e` is the `EventArgs` of the event provided to `DoWork`. You shouldn't need to use either of them.

Comment: I copied your code inside a button click event and called a function which runs pretty long inside it, nothing happened. It just skipped over the whole snippet. Time elapsed : 0.00 seconds

Comment: it runs asynchronously, so it would "seem" as though nothing is happening. put a breakpoint inside of the `DoWork` handler and you'll see that it's running.

Comment: Ahh I see, then how do I detect when the process has completed running?

Comment: here's more information on the background worker https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Since we now have async and await, there is no need to use the backgroundworker anymore unless you are using an older version of .NET. Threads and backgroundworker are oldfashioned ways of programmming. Using async and await is the way to go here.

Comment: that may be the case, i'm not sure. I was stuck in .NET 4.0 so I wasn't able to use those with WPF. I'll defer to others on how to use async/await in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that you have the UI thread trying to do all of the work. While the UI thread is working on a long term process, it isn't able to update your window.

What you want to do is let a separate thread handle the background process. This works well until the user wants to close the windows or cancel the current process. That's when you have to start worrying about the interactions between the UI thread and worker thread. To do this .Net gives us something called a cancellation token, that will allow us (if we wanted) to manually keep track of when to cancel a process.

The Cancellation Token is easily used with the [Task class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). You can complement this with the await/async so you don't have to manually check to wait on the completion of the task.

Your options will vary based on your current Framework.